# How to exclude or use Format_String for null values in MDX

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have this simple MDX query that brings back all elements under the customer hierarchy dimension (Customer Description, Customer Business, Customer ID).  The query executes fine but I need to exclude the rows that return #null.  I have tried using Non Empty but it is not working.

```
   WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Label] AS [Customer Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
   MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueName] AS [Customer Hierarchy].[Customer ID].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
SELECT 

    NON EMPTY {
    [Measures].[Label], 
        [Measures].[UniqueName]
        } ON COLUMNS 
    ,  NON EMPTY {[Customer Hierarchy].[Customer ID].ALLMEMBERS } ON ROWS 


FROM [SUMMARY]
```

Query Results (Customer, Customer Description, Customer ID)

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the output?

Comment: where is this being rendered? Excel? I'm not familiar with an output of #null from mdx

Comment: how can you have a uniquename for a member that is null - looks to me like there is something wrong with the cube

Comment: This is being rendered in Pentaho Report Designer.  It's a Mondrian Schema.

Answer (score 0):

To try to help diagnose what is happening - what do you get returned if you run this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Label] AS 
    [Customer Hierarchy].CurrentMember 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Label2] AS 
    [Customer Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueName] AS 
    [Customer Hierarchy].[Customer ID].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Label2]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Customer Hierarchy].[Customer ID].ALLMEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [SUMMARY];
```

Comment: With the query above I'm still getting the #null.  The query will fail unless I delete Member_Caption.

Comment: When using a computer generated MDX tool.  The following SET below was created to filter the '#null' values.  Unfortunately it does not bring back the members that I want and I'm having a difficult time converting it to a select.

Comment: SET    base AS 'FILTER([Customer Hierarchy].[Customer Division].MEMBERS,(ANCESTOR([Customer Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER, [Customer Hierarchy].[Customer Line Of Biz]) IN {[Customer Hierarchy].[MLS]}) AND ([Customer Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER NOT IN {[Customer Hierarchy].[Customer Division].[#null]} AND NOT ISEMPTY ([Measures].[Base GL Amt])))'